# Problems getting ether on testnet?

Tags: mining

I have just install Ethereum today so im a complete newbee to Ethereum and doing some research. I have installed the Ethereum Wallet app and synchronized the testnet.

However, to deploy my first contract in testnet, it requires some Ether, so can someone guide how to get that?
In Ethereum-Wallet, there is an option for CPU mining in the Develop menu. I try to use it to mine ethers (and win ethers) bt dosent work. It dont swich on.
Someone knows how can i resolve it.

Comment: Hi there. Your question could be interpreted in two ways: a) You'd just like some testnet ether, b) you'd like to know why you're failing to mine :-) If you'd like an answer to part b), then we'll need some more information. What do you mean when you say it doesn't switch on?

Comment: I want to mine to interact with the platform, I need some ether on the tesnet to start doing contracts... But when i click on minning the platform dosen't start running. I dont know why? You know? There are other metods to get some ether on the tesnet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a link that's been working for me:
https://www.reddit.com/r/ethdev/comments/61zdn8/if_you_need_some_ropsten_testnet_ethers/

Also the faucet works sometimes (can be slow):
http://faucet.ropsten.be:3001/

But also look at the TestRPC for running everything locally.  It can be really helpful when you just want to play around with some code.  Also, if you just want to test out your code (and don't care about having the wallet app installed), you can use the remix browser
 https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/#version=soljson-v0.4.13+commit.fb4cb1a.js

Comment: ty, but my first option is try to run the minning button.